# Rails, Postgres - Change column type from integer to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails 3.2 app that stores zip codes in a user_profiles table.  I originally used integer as the data type for zip codes; however, this is obviously wrong since you can't use numbers that start with zero (and some US zip codes do start with zero).  Therefore, I need to convert the zip code column AND my production data to string instead.  I think this is done with a simple change_column migration, but I don't know the exact code to use when using Postgres.  Any help would be much appreciated!  My original migration to add the zip code column is below:

```
class AddZipCodeToUserProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :user_profiles, :zip_code, :integer
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class ChangeZipCodeToString < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :user_profiles, :zip_code, :string
  end
end
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you joshua.paling!  Worked perfectly.  I was expecting some kind of error message from Postgres, but it went through with no errors.  Cheers.